# Vector mask adjustment layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, mask

I'm working on a calendar.  I have a grid of rectangle shapes that outline the days.  I'm trying to make a different adjustment layer for each day applied to a background.  It's basically working fine.  But once I create the adjustment layer, the region it applies to is fixed -- because I used the shape as a selection.  I'd like to be able to create a layer with a vector shape on it that has an adjustment associated with it that I can move around.

Here is what I'm doing now:

1. Select the rectangle shape (day) I want.
2. Go to paths palette and convert to selection.
3. Go back to layers palette, select the background layer, create new adjustment layer, and do the adjustment.

What would be cool is if I decide I want to move that day box around, I still could.

---

### Edit

What I would like to have is a vector defined region where an adjustment layer applies. For instance, suppose I have an image on one layer. I have an empty rectangle on another layer. I want to apply an adjustment ONLY where the vector is. This is because I want to have ANOTHER rectangle with a DIFFERENT adjustment. Suppose one rectangle enhances reds and the other greens, I would like to be able to move them around.

Answer (score 2):

Simply create an adjustment layer, place it above your vector layer then <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> click between the two layers to make a clipping mask. This way the Adjustment layer will only alter the layer it's linked to.

[image: clipping mask]

You can then move the associated vector layer and the clipped adjustment layer doesn't require any re-masking.

Comment: Well, the thing is, I'm not trying to apply the adjustment to the vector art itself.  What I would like to have is a vector defined region where an adjustment layer applies.  For instance, suppose I have an image on one layer.  I have an empty rectangle on another layer.  I want to apply an adjustment ONLY where the vector is.  This is because I want to have ANOTHER rectangle with a DIFFERENT adjustment.  Suppose one rectangle enhances reds and the other greens, I would like to be able to move them around.  Should I edit the question with this clarification?  Thanks.

Comment: errrr.. yeah all that would have been helpful to know from the start.